# When I add a row into a DataGrdiView i get “The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open”

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, sqlconnection

I have a datagridview (unbound) which is populated from MS SQL Server database. 
During the loop of reading information from DB and adding rows to the datagridview1 i get this message :“The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open” .

' **Here is the code**

```
Private Sub ShowMSR_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            Dim col As New CalendarColumn() With {.HeaderText = "ROS Date"}
            DataGridView1.Columns.Insert(5, col)
            Dim col_1 = New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
            col_1.Name = "Date"
            DataGridView1.Columns(5).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy"

            Dim strsqlcommand As String = "SELECT * FROM MSR Where MSR_ID='" & MSRID & "'"
            Dim dr As SqlDataReader
            Dim sqlcommand = New SqlCommand(strsqlcommand, Form1.SQL_conn)


            Dim itemcode As String = ""
            Dim Desc As String = " "
            Dim qty As String = " "
            Dim un As String = " "
            Dim AC As String = ""
            Dim comm As String = ""

                 Dim rdate As Date
                strsqlcommand = "Select Item_Code, Quantity, Unit, Item_Description, AC_No, ROS_time, Coment_RO From ITEMS Where MSR_ID
= '" & MSRID & "'"
                sqlcommand.CommandText = strsqlcommand
                dr = sqlcommand.ExecuteReader()
                While dr.Read()
                    itemcode = dr(0).ToString
                    qty = dr(1).ToString
                    un = dr(2).ToString
                    Desc = dr(3).ToString
                    AC = dr(4).ToString
                    If IsDBNull(dr(5)) Then
                        rdate = CDate("1990/1/1")
                    Else
                        rdate = CDate(dr(5))
                    End If

                    comm = dr(6).ToString

                    Dim row As String() = New String() {itemcode, qty, un, Desc, AC, rdate, comm}
                    Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row) '<---Here occur the problem 

                End While

                dr.Close()

                If (Form1.SQL_conn.State = ConnectionState.Open) Then Form1.SQL_conn.Close()

            Catch ex As Exception
              ' the exception is never triggered 
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
                If (Form1.SQL_conn.State = ConnectionState.Open) Then Form1.SQL_conn.Close()
            End Try
        End Sub
```

Comment: That is just horrendous for a number of reasons. Why would you be using an open connection from a different form here on this form? You should be creating, opening and closing connections where and when required. Keeping connections open on one form and using them in another form is just bad.

Comment: Apart from that, why would you be populating a grid like that in the first place? Create your data reader, bind that to a `BindingSource` and bind that to your grid. Done! You should read [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?887311).

Comment: And after all that @jmcilhinney said then search why concatenating strings to form sql command is another recipe for disasters. The term to search is Sql Injection

Comment: Finally, if the problem happens when you add a row then you should note that at that point the connection is open. This probably means that you have some code in the RowsAdded event that tries to work again with the connection without considering the open state of the connection. Now re-read the first comment and search about the Using statement.

Comment: Use `Using .. End Using method` with **Connection, SqlCommand and SqlDataReader** so all the open resources close, so you won't have to deal with Exceptions derived from remaining open resources like DataReader

Comment: _Arber Kule is a new contributor. Be nice._